# How to add a maximize button to a floating QDockWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qdockwidget

How can I add a maximize button to a floating QDockWidget?

I read about a method with creating a custom titlebar but I would prefer using the standard buttons instead of icons I have to add myself.

The best solution would be if the title bar style wouldn't change when it's made floating.

[image: Dock widget screenshot]

Comment: I just tried a code that generates a floating QDockWidget and keep the buttons, you could show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be able to test your code.

Comment: Not so easy in my case as the dock widget is inherited and templated, but I will try to get a working example within the next days. Hoped for a good guess though.

Comment: I recommend that every time you ask questions you provide a mvce, according to my experience that type of question is more likely to be answered than those who do not have it, as it helps us understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Initially a floating window will have the following flags: QFlags<Qt::WindowType>(Tool|X11BypassWindowManagerHint|WindowTitleHint|WindowSystemMenuHint|CustomizeWindowHint|WindowCloseButtonHint)

You will need to set the Qt::CustomizeWindowH and add to the other flags on the dock widget the flags Qt:WindowMaximizeButtonHint (or WindowMinMaxButtonsHint) and respectively the Qt:FramelessWindowHint (depending on the system visu you use - need also the X11 flag to set) QFlags<Qt::WindowType>(Tool|X11BypassWindowManagerHint|FramelessWindowHint)

Setting the flag will need to be done using the method setWindowFlags:https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop

Additionally there is another method: setWindowFlag(flag,bool):https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setWindowFlag

Comment: I was not able to get it to work. 
My code is: dockWidget->setWindowFlags(Qt::Tool | Qt::WindowMinMaxButtonsHint | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowTitleHint | Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

But I also tried other combinations, no change unfortunately.

Comment: I am sorry, you are right, the maximize and minimize buttons cannot be added to a Qt::Tool and Qt::FramelessWindowHint. You need to make it a Window when it is outside (topLevelChange signal) but this time, you will have the dockWidget presented as a window and not as a normal Docking with Frameleess decoration.